# Loop never ends in SQL Server using While Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

```
While Exists (Select * From Col Where Depth Is Null)
    Update T
    Set T.Depth = P.Depth + 1,
        T.Lineage = P.Lineage + LTrim(Str(T.ParentId, 6, 0)) + '/'
    From Col T
    Join Col P On T.ParentId = P.Id
    Where
        P.Depth >= 0
        And P.Lineage Is Not Null
        And T.Depth Is Null
```

Comment: Daniel: Please be constructive instead in your comment. 

My guess is abhi234u doesn´t understand how to indent the code.. to add your code, you need 4 spaces before the text that should be added as code snippets

Comment: Was there a *question*? Or is this a report of the status of your current development efforts?  If the (implied) question is "Why am I observing this behavior?",  the most likely explanation is that there are rows in `Col` with `Depth IS NULL` which are never (and will never) be updated. For example, if there's a row in Col that has `(ParentId, Depth)` tuple values of `(NULL,NULL)`, that row won't be affected by the UPDATE statement.

Comment: There was a question earlier, but he had added the code as an image, after I instructed on how to add text as code, the former question was removed in the edit i think. Also he wrote in the question that the query gives the correct output, so I think BEGIN and END tags would instruct the code to know what part of the query code should be affected by the WHILE loop. It is somewhat of a guess since we don´t know if there is code following the code in question

Comment: Could it be that one of the parent identifiers is null? If it is your join will not evaluate to true and therefore will never update the depth for that row.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're trying to do a recursive query, and the standard way to do that is with a CTE:

```
;WITH rec AS(
SELECT c.Id, c.Depth, CAST(c.Id AS varchar(MAX) + '/' AS Lineage
    FROM Col c
    WHERE c.ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c1.Id, rec.Depth + 1, rec.Lineage + CAST(c1.id as varchar(10)) + '/'
    FROM rec
    INNER JOIN Col c1 on rec.Id = c1.ParentId
    WHERE rec.Depth < 100 --Limit the recursion, set this to what is appropriate for your data
)
--SELECT * FROM rec --Use this first to see if the data is correct, then:
UPDATE T
SET T.Depth = r.Depth, T.Lineage = r.Lineage
FROM Col T
INNER JOIN rec r ON T.Id = r.Id
```

For more information about CTE's, you can check [this technet link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Kateract, I tried your code but getting the below error.Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "LINEAGE" of recursive query "rec".

Comment: Try with the above changes, using Cast instead of Str.

Comment: Kateract, No rows are affected with the sql. Thanks

Comment: Does the data come back if you use the Select instead of the Update?  You can only use one at a time, the CTE can only be used for the next statement.

Comment: Data does not come back in  the select. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's anything else I can change without information about your data.  If you could edit your question to include some sample data it would be helpful.

Comment: Kateract, I was implementing the same code from the below link http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql    . Hope this helps..Thanks

Comment: That tutorial is from 2002, so you'd probably be better off using a newer one.  As it is, your column names are different from what they are specifying in the tutorial, so the changes that need to be made are not clear unless you post what you are actually using.  If your table were like the example, the recursion would be based on Node and ParentNode and EmployeeID would be a data field that you could use to update the table.  You have ID and ParentID which doesn't match up with what they show.